# I want to test the statistical significance of the NDVI change in R

Tags: r, remote-sensing, ndvi, sentinel-2, statistics

I have 20 Sentinel 2 satellite data for the period from 2017 to 2020, with 5 satellite scenes each for the months from May to September, covering one vegetation season. I am interested in whether the drought in 2018 had a significant impact on a specific forest. To investigate this, I want to test the statistical significance of the NDVI change in R. I have already calculated the NDVI, and now I am looking for an appropriate test.

Initially, I considered conducting paired t-tests to compare individual time points with each other. However, I noticed that I obtained significant results even for minor changes. In the literature, I came across the Mann-Kendall test, which may not work well with seasonal data, and I would need to average the NDVI values. Additionally, this test typically requires a time span of 8-10 years, which is not possible with Sentinel-2 data, making it unsuitable for my analysis.

Can you suggest any other tests to examine the change/trend? ?

Comment: NDVI is not optimal for measuring water stress. Before you proceed with any analysis, consider using a spectral index that is sensitive to canopy moisture content.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of model specification, fitting, and inference. Underneath the name of a Famous Statistician, most statistical tests are really a model specified in terms of probability distributions and parameters. You are free to model your data using any probability distributions, parameters, and functions of those things.

The first thing to do is to really nail down what you want to know. Its not enough to say "I want to see if 2018 is different to 2017", because we know that's true. Its not enough to say "Is 2018 significantly different to 2017", because you've not defined a model which you can look at the uncertainty in the parameters to infer anything at some significance level.

You've got 5 months of data from 4 years. You expect a seasonal pattern over those five months. That part of the model you can maybe fit with a sinusoidal curve, with the same parameters for each year. Then for each year you have a set of parameters which model the average NDVI value for that year. Then maybe everything else is just random uncorrelated noise. Your model is then:

```
NDVI_y = A.sin(t/12) + B.cos(t/12) + C_y + Noise
```

Where `NDVI_y` is the `NDVI` in year `y` and `C_y` is the fitted average in year `y`, and `t` is month. You also need to consider the distribution of the noise - its possibly normally distributed with mean zero and unknown variance, but you might have to do something trickier since NDVI is constrained (I think) and so treating it as a sample from a normal distribution isn't perfect since the normal distribution is unbounded...

Then you look at the fitted `C_y` values, and their uncertainty which you get from, for example, the `glm` function, and an "analysis of variance" will tell you if they are the same within the uncertainty granted the model from the noise distribution. And this all depends on your model being correctly specified for your data too, but these are things you test with diagnostics.

As described so far I'm talking about one pixel of 20 year-month values in your data. You could do this independently for each set of 20 year-month values in your data and map the fitted parameters, but then any inference on a single pixel is weak because you are doing thousands (for a large grid) of statistical tests, and the [XKCD Jelly Bean](https://xkcd.com/882/) comic rule applies. But as a quick test to look for large areas of significantly different NDVI values, its a start.

Note this model has 7 parameters (two for the seasonal, 5 for the months) which is quite a lot for only 20 data points. If you are more interested in asking the question "is it increasing?" then your model would be more like:

```
NDVI_y = A.sin(t/12) + B.cos(t/12) + C + D.t + Noise
```

which is like fitting a straight line through the points after considering the seasonal pattern. You then have a constant parameter C and a slope parameter D, and if D is greater than zero then you've got an increase at whatever significance dependent on the parameter uncertainty.

I could go on but I've probably made enough mistakes here already, but moving from asking "What test do I use?" to thinking about your data and designing a model for fitting using R's modelling code is a big and powerful step in data analysis.

Comment: I know that one should not say thank you and I can delete the comment, but thank you for your detailed response and the time you took to provide me with food for thought in a relatively new subject area for me. I plan to dig into model creation, which I expect will require a significant amount of time and dedication.

Answer (score 1):

### Sample size

As I see it, you only have 5 NDVI measurements per annum, which is a small sample size for significance testing. To increase the number of NDVI values, you could fit a seasonal trend line and then interpolate new values at finer intervals. But this introduces uncertainty regarding the accuracy of the trend line. TLDR: I suspect you will need more than 5 NDVI observations per annum for a rigorous analysis.

### Visual data exploration

I would first explore the data with visual aids. For example, a boxplot or violin plot of NDVI values categorised by year. This will give you a visual indication whether 2018 was unusual.

### Statistical data analysis

**One-way ANOVA** could be used to test the significance of any differences in mean NDVI between years (at the 95% or 99% confidence intervals). There are several post-hoc tests (e.g., Tukey) that could tell you specifically whether mean NDVI in 2018 was significantly different.

Other tests would require more than 5 samples per year. For example, you could compare the distribution of NDVI values for each year using the **[K-sample Anderson–Darling test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderson%E2%80%93Darling_test)**. This tests the null hypothesis that the NDVI observations are drawn from the same population, and thus would share a common empirical distribution. Deviations from this empirical distribution could indicate an abnormal year. This test is useful because:

- multiple years can be compared simultaneously,
- the shape of the empirical distribution does not have to be specified *a priori*.

### Correlation analysis - a better approach?

> I am interested in whether the drought in 2018 had a significant impact on a specific forest.

Why not measure the "impact" directly, then investigate the correlation with NDVI? For example, count the number of dead trees, then test whether the number of dead trees is related to NDVI or low rainfall?

- Perhaps test for correlations with **spectral indices that are more sensitive to water stress than NDVI? The SWIR bands are more sensitive to canopy water content**.
- Perhaps the change in NDVI is related to other factors such as pests & disease?

Comment: Thank you for your input and effort. I will investigate the required sample size for the K-sample Anderson-Darling test or explore how to calculate the necessary sample size for my dataset. I am concerned about whether cloudier years will provide enough samples during the vegetation period. In any case, as you suggested, I will focus on water stress-sensitive indices and assess whether a correlation analysis with tree mortality or climate parameters is more suitable for me.